# Spring social AuthorizationException with Facebook

Tags: facebook, spring-social, http-status-code-500

Between 7.30 PM CET and 8.30 PM CET at the 27th of March my website suddenly reported this error when logging in with Facebook:

> HTTP Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)

**Message:** Authorization is required for the operation, but the API binding was created without authorization.

```
Exception: org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException
```

The site/server has been running untouched since end of last year. Does anybody know if something was done at that particular day?

Comment: @CBroe I have the exact same problem. This question couldn't have described it better. Suddenly (today) my website has started reporting the same error when trying to log in with Facebook. My assumption is that something has expired. But the supposed duplicate doesn't even seem to answer my question at all (it's going on about upgrading the version of something). Have you linked to the wrong question?

Comment: I understand your question. I also looked at the duplicated and did only understand that the Facebook API has changed and it is indeed the problem that I had but since I am using Spring Social I have not written any code at the level described in that answer. 
But the solution for me was do upgrade to a newer version of Spring Social. Then it, I assume, use a later version of the Facebook API.