# Spring social Authorisation Exception with Facebook

Tags: java, spring-social

My website has suddenly started reporting this error when ever anyone logs in with Facebook:

> **HTTP Status 500 - Authorization is required for the operation, but the
>   API binding was created without authorization.**
>
> **type** Exception report
>
> **message** Authorization is required for the operation, but the API
>   binding was created without authorization.
>
> **description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> **exception** org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException:
>   Authorization is required for the operation, but the API binding was
>   created without authorization.

I have not changed anything relating to Facebook logging in recently, so why might my website be suddenly giving this error?

Comment: This question is very similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153206/spring-social-authorizationexception-with-facebook), which I found while trying to find the answer to my identical problem. Eureka! Except that question had been closed as being a supposed duplicate of another and the answer to that supposed duplicate were no help whatsoever (as is often the case). So, I have spent a lot more time finding out the answer myself and here is the same question together with what I have found out so far, which may be of help to the next person (surely the _whole point_ of SO).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that version 2.2 of Facebook's Graph API (which is used for this kind of thing) ceased to be available on 25/3/17: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog. Hence, the sudden change in behaviour in spite of there being no change to my website.

My website uses v1.1.0 of the spring-social-facebook library. I suspect this is the problem and that I ought to be using v2.0.3: http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/. However, I don't have the skills to take this any further.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I changed spring-social-facebook from version 1.1.1.RELEASE to version 2.0.3.RELEASE, and problem solved.